# How to subquery Firebase Web App to Create a table

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing a basic e-commerce web platform, so the user can buy products, and in other page I want to show his product list, and the orders, what I mean is that a user can make one or more orders with 1 or more products.

the UID is the email.
this is my data structure

```
{
  "Orders" : {
    "-L-Nor4Ld1NNORxNToPI" : {
      "order" : [ {
        "cant" : "1",
        "product_id" : "1"
      }, {
        "cant" : "2",
        "product_id" : "5"
      }, {
        "cant" : "3",
        "product_id" : "8"
      } ],
      "status" : "pendiente",
      "total" : 795,
      "user_id" : "email@gmail.com"
    },
    "-L-UU03CNGSPd8o0UCHn" : {
      "order" : [ {
        "cant" : "2",
        "product_id" : "2"
      }, {
        "cant" : "1",
        "product_id" : "7"
      } ],
      "status" : "pendiente",
      "total" : 280,
      "user_id" : "email@gmail.com"
    },
    "any" : {
      "order" : {
        "product1" : {
          "cant" : 1,
          "product_id" : 1
        },
        "product2" : {
          "cant" : 1,
          "product_id" : 1
        }
      },
      "status" : "delivered",
      "total" : 100.01,
      "user_id" : "email@example.com"
    }
  },
  "Productos" : {
    "-L-JT-TaL5ctRQ-8u8NR" : {
      "price" : 35,
      "product_id" : 1,
      "product_name" : "Serie 100 luces (foco)",
      "stock" : 20
    },
    "-L-JTIcZ69uFkdUQbs8X" : {
      "price" : 75,
      "product_id" : 2,
      "product_name" : "Serie 100 luces (LED)",
      "stock" : 10
    },
    "-L-JTTi8VcLxkgT3RNuA" : {
      "price" : 70,
      "product_id" : 3,
      "product_name" : "Serie 140 luces musical (foco)",
      "stock" : 10
    },
    "-L-JTb0PwTyS8TiWS5W9" : {
      "price" : 96,
      "product_id" : 4,
      "product_name" : "Serie 140 luces musical (LED)",
      "stock" : 10
    },
    "-L-JUm5tF8fYBmR3BZCU" : {
      "price" : 110,
      "product_id" : 5,
      "product_name" : "Serie 300 luces color",
      "stock" : 10
    },
    "-L-JUzclafELx1xjpuQx" : {
      "price" : 135,
      "product_id" : 6,
      "product_name" : "Serie 300 luces blanca",
      "stock" : 10
    },
    "-L-JVB8diTZMmVS3ay1u" : {
      "price" : 130,
      "product_id" : 7,
      "product_name" : "Cascada 400 Luces",
      "stock" : 10
    },
    "-L-JVIgENEJRdcfLfKWT" : {
      "price" : 180,
      "product_id" : 8,
      "product_name" : "Manguera gel 10 metros",
      "stock" : 10
    }
  }
}
```

And you can see the project by yourself just login with google in  this link
[Go To Project](https://instaledbuy.firebaseapp.com)
once you have made your order, you can go to this link [Order review Page](https://instaledbuy.firebaseapp.com/cart.html)
and you should see whats in your order, but that doesnt happens, I want to do something like this

Get logged user_id then get user_id orders(order_id), then show in (if) multiple tables with

`|Product |Price| Quantity| sub(price*quant)`

And its products

So as you can see in the code of cart.html im using

```
ref.orderBy(X).equalTo(uid).on("child_added",function(data){
    ref.orderBy(Y).equalTo(item).on("child_added",function(data2){
        //dothings create table content
    })
    //close table content 
})
//embed table content created.
```

so I want to show a the table but `.then()` function doesnt work and the same with `.done()` , i hope you can help me to understand how should I subquery, to get the user orders in a table

Comment: What do you expect this code to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was not to get values by inner firebase functions, it was getting all the data, then create the table with the data

The next code suppose that productsObj, and ordersObj are the result objects of my firebase database products and orders.
so the next thing i did was to create dynamically the table with this function. 
You cannot create subqueries or something like that on firebase functions like `on`  `child_added`, `child_removed`, etc..

```
function productList(){

    if(ordersObj.length != 0 & productsObj.length == 8){
        //console.log("si termino");    
        $.each(ordersObj,function(index, data){
            var table =('<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">');
            var tableHead = ("<thead class='thead-dark'><tr><th>Producto</th><th>Precio</th><th>Cantidad</th><th>Importe</th></thead>");
            table+=tableHead;
            //console.log(table);
            var tableBody = ("");
            //console.log(tableBody)
            var total = 0;
            $.each(data.order,function(idx, ord){
                console.log(ord.product_id);
                //console.log("precio:"+productsObj[ord.product_id-1].price);
                var subtotal = ord.cant*productsObj[ord.product_id-1].price;
                //console.log("despues del subtotal")
                var row = ('<tr><td>'+productsObj[ord.product_id-1].product_name+'</td><td>'+productsObj[ord.product_id-1].price+'</td>'+'<td>'+ord.cant+'</td>'+'<td>'+subtotal+'</td></tr>');
                //console.log(row);
                total=data.total;
                tableBody+=(row);
            });
                //console.log(tableBody.html());
                //console.log(tableHead.html());
            tableBody+=("<tr><td colspan='2'>Total</td><td colspan='2'>"+total+"</td></tr><tbody></table>");
            table+=tableBody;
            //console.log(table);
            //table.append(tableHead.html());
            $('#content').append(table);
            $('#content').append("<br>");
        });




    }
    else{
        //productList();
    }

}
```